# Is it possible to make Entity Framework (Core) ignore missing columns when writing, to support backwards compatibility with old databases

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, backwards-compatibility

We are using Entity Framework Core to access multiple versions of our database.

We would like to have a single tool be able to work with a range of versions of the database. But if a new column has been added to a table when we use EF to write to an older database that doesn't yet have the new column we get this exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'SomeNewColumn'
```

We could have code that checked the version, and marked these columns to be ignored.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (databaseVersion < versionThatSupportsNewColumn)
        modelBuilder.Entity<ModelType>().Ignore(x => x.SomeNewColumn);
}
```

But is there a way to tell Entity Framework to just automatically ignore missing columns when doing updates rather than throwing the exception? So we don't have to go through adding every new column to get the backwards compatible support working.

(We're using EF core, but an answer for EF 6 would be equally interesting)

Comment: Always include in a Database a version number.  Entity has a mapping file and the mapping file has to be compatible with all version of database.  Then in code depending on version of database, your code will manage the differences.

Comment: @jdweng we do have a version number stored in the database. But we don't use EF to manage migrations between versions. We're using 'code first' so I don't think there is a mapping file, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: *automatically ignore missing columns* -- There's not such a thing in EF. And it would be really hard, because a new version may also have business logic depending on the new columns, or new columns may be required. I think in reality you don't even want this.

Comment: The mapping file has to be a superset of the different versions of the database if you want to use only one mapping file.

Comment: @jdweng, by 'mapping file' are you talking about the model classes? We don't have any separate mapping file.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, if it doesn't exist that pretty much answers the question, we'll just have to stick to the manual method.

Comment: @GertArnold I get what you're saying about it being hard in the general case to handle this in an app, but I'm talking about a more narrow case here where I just want to support working with old versions of a database without having to manually code around every column that doesn't exist in the old version. We're building an internal tool that does some admin tasks, and it just would make for easier maintenance if we could just tell it just to ignore columns that don't exist. We are still going to build the backwards compatibility support, but just with manually handling each new column.

Comment: Yes the model is a mapping file.  Sometimes an EDMX.

Comment: @jdweng Ok, right. So no EDMX because we're doing code first. But basically you are saying there is no way to do this automatically as the model must always be a superset of all supported versions, so the new column has to be excluded or marked as ignored to make it work with old versions. Thanks.

Comment: I think the common approach is to always update the database to the current version. If this is not feasible I would guess it should be possible to maintain separate models for each version and an abstraction layer on top. But that would be a hassle to maintain.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks, for the suggestion. We're building an tool to perform admin functions for customers using different versions. We specifically want the tool to be backwards compatible with at least the last few versions that are still under our list of supported releases. We don't want to require the customers to upgrade before they are ready. Maintaining a separate module for each version is definitely out of the question. If EF doesn't support this scenario, we're going to either use code to manually ignore each column based on the version number, or we might consider doing it in plain SQL.